# Why does call to an undefined function does not give a compiler error and gives linker error in C?

Tags: function, compiler-errors, linker-errors, undefined-reference

If in a C program I call a function that is not defined or declared anywhere in the scope then I will get an error at the linking time but not at the compile time. I wonder why does this not generate an error at the compile time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, like in other programming languages, the compilation process is made of two main steps:

1. Compiling
2. Linking

In the first step all the functions, with respective signatures (that are enough for the moment), **must be declared and visibile** in the scope of the caller. This step produces an **object** file, that is a file which contains a machine code, relocatable and not yet executable.

In the second and final step the object file is **linked** to the system and/or user libraries. Each declared function is **now** resolved to its implemented counterpart (**now if it does not exist the linker generates the error**) and made executable.

This is the reason.

Comment: That is understandable. Unlike a function call if I try to use an undefined variable in the code then I get an error at the compile time. Why is it different in the case of an undefined variable?

Comment: A variable is like a function: they cannot be referenced if not declared. It a basic of any compiled programming language.

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more why a undefined variable cannot be referenced while an undefined function can?

Comment: As I stated functions cannot be undefined, they msut be declared, but implemented later in a library or object file. I suggest you to read some article like these https://www.google.com/search?q=compiling%20and%20linking .